# Can I share one PlayStation+ account between two PS4's?

Tags: psn, playstation-plus

I just bought a second PS4.  I have one in the living room and one in my game room.  My son uses the one in the game room.  I only have 1 PlayStation Plus account.  If I make the new PlayStation my primary PlayStation, how can my son use the one in the game room to play all the free PlayStation plus games?

Comment: ....this is where it gets very complicated and Sony doesn't understand this concept apparently.....

Answer (score 4):

According to the [PlayStation FAQ](http://faq.en.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/249/original_article/6805/related/1/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xNDQzNzE3OTgzL3NpZC93MkRvQVN4bQ%3D%3D):

> You can only activate one PS4™ as your ‘Primary PS4’.

Your primary PS4 has unrestricted access to all content on all accounts. But a non-primary PS4 can only access the content while logged in.

Here's what you can do: set up your son's PS4 as your primary PS4. That way, he will be able to use the Plus features while logged on his account. The downside is that on your PS4, you have to log into your PSN account to do anything, that means you'll be blocked if the Internet is out.

This is entirely different on the PS3, as it allows you to activate two unrestricted consoles.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually tried it but I believe it works like this.

If your account is registered on **both** systems, all other accounts on those systems will be able to play PSN games (with their own save files ofcourse).
You need to *purchase* the game on the ps store (for free if it comes with ps+) using **your** account.
Then it can be played using **any account on the same system**.

Check the comments for more details. Apparently this only works when online. (Thanks Dupree3!)

Comment: could you go into more detail then "trust me, it will work"?

Comment: Nope, that is how I always believed it worked. Considering the downvote and your comment I might actually be wrong.

Comment: this is true, but you MUST BE ONLINE to do play those games. I game share with a friend and it is very complicated and you can lose access to your own games.

Comment: Okay, so a lot of things changed from ps3 to ps4? I have more experience with the ps3. At first sight the ps4 looked similar.